# Lower and Upper case issues in SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have drawn line and a circle using two paths in SVG. I have used gradient units property for linear gradient in SVG and I have applied the gradient color to the circle and line. While applying into DOM the "`gradientUnits`" property is applied as "`gradientunits`"; because of this Upper and Lower case issue I was not able to get my required output.

Image 1:
Having issue 
[image]
mentioned in green colored rectangle.

Image 2: Required output
[image]
mentioned in green colored rectangle.

Here is my SVG code:

`<svg id="legend_container_svg" class="e-designerhide" style="height: 40px; width: 71px;">
<g id="container_svg_Legend">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="container_svg_legend0Gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="558%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F34649" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#B74143" stop-opacity="1"></stop></linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <g id="container_svg_Legend0" cursor="pointer">
        <path id="container_svg_LegendItemShape0" fill="url(#container_svg_legend0Gradient)" stroke-width="2" stroke="url(#container_svg_legend0Gradient)" opacity="1" d="M 7.5 21.5 L 12.5 21.5 M 22.5 21.5 L 27.5 21.5" lgndctx="true"></path>
        <path id="container_svg_LegendItemShape0" fill="transparent" stroke-width="2" stroke="url(#container_svg_legend0Gradient)" opacity="1" d="M 12.5 21.5 a 5 5 0 1 0 10 0 a5 5 0 1 0 -10 0" lgndctx="true"></path>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>`

Is there any method in JavaScript to apply the attribute property in DOM as if what I have given in my source code?

Anyone help me on resolving the issue.

Thanks, Dharani.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `element.setAttribute(attrName, attrValue)`